# Saving to end of exsisting text file c#

Tags: c#, save, streamwriter

I have the following code written as I want to save a string to the end of a text file in the form of a list.

However, at the moment when I try to save something, it deletes all previous text in the file and just adds the most recent one. The following is my code:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Falconex\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Test2\Test2\bin\Debug\Product.txt"))
{
    writer.WriteLine(productTextBox.Text + Environment.NewLine);
    writer.Close();
}
```

Thank you in advance, Lucy

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're currently just overwriting the contents of the file, every time you write.

StreamWriter has a second parameter you have to set to true to append text:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Path\To\file.txt", true))
{
    writer.WriteLine(productTextBox.Text + Environment.NewLine);
    writer.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it more easier. Use some of static methods on class "File" (AppendAllLines, AppendText, AppendAllText). For example:

```
 File.AppendAllLines("filename.txt", new string[] { "my appended text" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to add this code to new StreamWriter constructor

```
new FileStream(@"path/to/file", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)
```

for more info look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/wtbhzte9(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are overwriting the previous content. You need to read the content first store it temporarily and write again with the new text. Something like this:

```
//Reading text
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Falconex\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Test2\Test2\bin\Debug\Product.txt");
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Falconex\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Test2\Test2\bin\Debug\Product.txt"))
{
    writer.WriteLine(text + productTextBox.Text + Environment.NewLine);
    writer.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Falconex\Documents\Visual         Studio 2015\Projects\Test2\Test2\bin\Debug\Product.txt",true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(productTextBox.Text + Environment.NewLine);
                writer.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filepath, true))
    {
        {
        writer.Write(productTextBox.Text + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    writer.Close();
    }
```

that `true` parameter tells the `StreamWriter` to Append the text if the file exists